# Apache Ingite 2.14.0 h2 query engine failing with: "uniqueAlias" is null error

Tags: h2, ignite

Apache Ingite 2.14.0, using the default H2 query processor, fails with the following error:

`class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.sql.GridSqlAlias.alias()" because "uniqueAlias" is null`

when parsing a particular query I have.  The SQL is a bit funky as it is produced by another tool, but is nevertheless valid.

I've tried to boil it down to the simplest case possible that exposes the issue.  Using this sample:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
   ACCT_CD VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
   ACCT_TYP_CD VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO TEST (ACCT_CD, ACCT_TYP_CD) VALUES ('TEST', 'TEST');
```

This SQL triggers the above exception:

```
SELECT ACCT_CD
  FROM (
    SELECT ACCT_CD
      FROM (
         SELECT ACCT_CD
           FROM TEST
      )
  );
```

Oddly if I change the 2nd SELECT to use a wildcard the query succeeds without a problem:

```
SELECT ACCT_CD
  FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM (
         SELECT ACCT_CD
           FROM TEST
      )
  );
```

Note: this same query that fails above succeeds when using the Calcite query processor:

```
SELECT /*+ QUERY_ENGINE('calcite') */ ACCT_CD
  FROM (
    SELECT ACCT_CD
      FROM (
         SELECT ACCT_CD
           FROM TEST
      )
  );
```

I had started with a fairly complex query that was producing the problem tried to simplify it to the minimum setup that still exposed the issue.

I'm wondering if there is something that can be done with how the Ignite is set up that will get around this problem.

Comment: Looks to be a bug in ignite-h2.

Comment: I agree with Alex. You can submit a jira to address this issue, however afaik community goal is to push Ignite toward calcite usage, so I'm not sure that this bug will be eventually fixed.

Comment: Okay that's basically what I suspected.  Thanks